# pdo prepare in string concatenation

Tags: sql-server, string, pdo, datatable, backend

My question is quite odd, I have a php backend for mssql with pdo and I can't use the prepare statement that escape string as design because my query is built from more string concatenation. This backend serve a datatable project and performs serverside query with ajax.

The backend bug is the impossibility to send to the db special chars because the target is not escaped. Is very hard implement the standard escapng with prepare because I have not a single point where build queries. When queries are sent to the db the targets are already written in a string and I can't use prepare.

Just to make sure I will post this php function:
[nopaste of concrete php script](http://pastie.org/p/4pJfLlKGMxDt9ubWp2oHQ1)

It uses a custom pdo class, but I don't think is important right now.

I was wondering if there was a way to use the standard prepare that comes from pdo, instead of put directly the strings $global_target and $individual_target I can use two placeholder that will be substitute by the real strings, acting in this way I can't control how many interrogatives use for the pdo prepare statement, because a classic prepare statement is

> $resultset =
> $db->query($sql)->bind(1,$myvar)->bind(2,$myvar2)->bind(...)->resultset();

The $sql in my case is dynamically built and I don't know how many searches send the user, so it's a not good strategy.

To cut short, I need a tip to escape the input searches that comes with two string variable.
Regards.

Comment: You could do the concatenation in the query using the [`concat()` SQL function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or the [`+` concatenation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and just pass the single substrings as parameters. Or just fix the weird architecture maybe.

Comment: The problem is how handle the input target when contains special char before sql receive the query, when the query is a variable yet

Comment: Use only parameters. Don't try any escaping "yourself" (or with any `*escape*()` functions. It'll get get escaped just once and in the right way.

Comment: Can you write a sample for line 97 for global search, and for line 162 for the individual search?

Comment: I think I need a function to encode/decode this strings, a kind of json stringify

Comment: Post the *relevant* code **in the question as text** by [edit]ing it. Don't post links, don't post images. If necessary, because the actual code is too much, compose a [example].

Comment: Is hard to minimize the code because each line explains the why of the constructs, but I will do

Comment: Aside... `@TableName NVARCHAR(45) = 'View_Presentation'` is applying an ASCII string literal to an nvarchar scalar, luckily it only contains ASCII characters. Get into the habit of using National literals with nvarchar columns and scalars, e.g.: `@TableName NVARCHAR(45) = N'View_Presentation'`.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I had not really thought about it.

Comment: I still missing an approach to fix the main problem

Comment: I'm finding hard to figure out how to use parameters only, I must copy to a string before send to sql, and sql need escape too

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved with a simple string replace of php. This try is been done yet as 1st attempt, but this time I replaced the single quote with 4 quotes when take the string from the parameters. That's all for now, regards.